# Is there a way to put a border inside an Element instead of Outside?

Tags: jquery, css, border

Im working with jQuery and CSS. When I use a `mouseenter` event for an image (to put a border around the image), the layout gets tweeked because of the outside border, which makes it pretty ugly.  I was just wondering if there's a way to put the border inside of the img so that the img container remains the same size and doesn't affect the layout.  The only thing I can think of is to resize the image in the `mouseevent`, which just seems like a lot of work (figuring out sizes, especially considering responsiveness), and I can see a lot of problems arising from doing this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually you cannot use `border` property for having a border inside an element, workaround for this is to use `box-shadow` set to `inset`

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #000;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qcRKN/) (This will generate a blurred border, to get a nice solid one, refer the demo below)

---

Get some more solidity

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 red, inset 0 -1px 0 red, inset 1px 0 0 red, inset 0 1px 0 red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qcRKN/2/)

Comment: Do I have to wrap the `img` in a `div` or can I use the `box-shadow` for an `img` also?

Comment: @peeskillet You need to use pseudo after before than, better wrap the images with `span`, use `padding`, set the `span` to `inline-block`

Answer (score 3):

Adjusting the padding works.

```
#something {
    padding: 12px;
}
#something:hover {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 4px solid #FF0000;
}
```

`box-shadow` is not supported in older browsers.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/MmdrE/).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:after` pseudo element selector.

```
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

div:hover:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    bottom: 1px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/qcRKN/1/)

Comment: Legit solution !

Comment: `:before` is better if it's not `:hover` and in case it has clickable events in it. E.g. a button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>

<style>
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
div#div2:hover {
    height: 196px;
    width: 196px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ET2De/